# How to float nav-item to the right when links collapsed

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm modifying an example nav bar I intend to use for the mobile version of the website only, however, the right hand text won't float fully to the right-hand side and upon the links collapsing, the centralised brand is no longer central.

I'd like to keep the brand centred and the right-hand text pushed to the right after the links collapse into the burger menu.

[**Codeply**](https://www.codeply.com/go/h0ixYALMvf)

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-xl bg-success justify-content-between">
     <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-nav">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-1 order-md-0">
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
           </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block text-center order-0 order-md-1 w-25">Brand</a>
        <div class="dual-nav w-50 order-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">float me right</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reconfigured a few of your items. Hope this helps.

```css
.navbar-toggler {
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
}

.navbar-right a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-xl bg-success justify-content-between">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block text-center order-0 order-md-1 w-25">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-nav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-1 order-md-0">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-right"><a class="nav-link" href="">float me right</a></div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect - the aspect that isn't quite right is that when the screen size is >769px the 'brand' appears below the links in the expandable section

Comment: I cannot replicate that in the fiddle, I do now see that it is more to the right than centered though. You can add the css from above to a media query so when the screen size is under 769 the code runs

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `justify-content: end;` to the `nav` selector's CSS or add the `justify-content-end` class to the `nav` with jQuery.

Comment: This works whilst the links are in the nav, but once the links collapse into the burger menu, the brand and the right-hand text shift left